# Daum Potplayer prevent playlist on right edge

Tags: daum-pot-player

Potplayer has the behaviour of popping up a playlist window if you move the mouse cursor to the right edge of a fullscreen video - I find it very annoying. You can disble this with F6 on a per-video basis, but have not been able to find any setting to disable it permanently. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

if you have latest version of pot player go to preference settings, playback ,full screen mode,then deselect box pop up window pane,after this playlist should be disable.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and this is the solution.

1. Preference > General > Skins > Untick "Auto hide main window skin while video screen is active"
2. Press "Open/Hide playlist" (the yellow icon) on the video you are watching to hide the playlist panel.
3. Tick "Auto hide main window skin while video screen is active"

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers actually works but I fixed mine by creating a new config:
Preferences > Configuration > Add
then just change the "*default preset" on the top-left to new config you created.